# how to get Data from this JSON

Tags: java, android

how to get Name and UserName from this JSON 

String str="{Name=jack,UserName=Jacki}" 

in java android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: please SEE the FORMAT of my str

Comment: did you try split function?

Comment: No. How to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, code will use scanner class and its findInLine() method

```
String str="{Name=jack,UserName=Jacki}";
Scanner sc=new Scanner(str);
sc.findInLine("Name=");

 if(sc.hasNext())
 {
     System.out.println(sc.next()); //This will print Name you can store it in variable as well
  }


sc.findInLine("UserName=");

if(sc.hasNext())
 {
     System.out.println(sc.next()); //This will print UserName you can store it in variable as well
  }
```

Comment: thanks.
but What is "sc" ?

Comment: Sorry due to some typing mistake i had not specified the Scanner class code but right now i have edited it, If you are satified please upvote it.

Comment: thanks it i working but the Name shows Like this : jack,
<br/> the "," is shown

Comment: As in the code posted as an answer by @anurag joshi just try to split the string using split method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Sample
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str="{Name=jack,UserName=Jacki}";
        String[] str1=str.split(",");
        System.out.print(str1[0].substring(1));
        System.out.print(str1[1].substring(0,str1[1].length()-1));
    }
}
```

So in this method you basically take the string and split it on the ",". That gives you {Name=jack and UserName=Jacki}. The next two statements just parse these 2 new strings and remove the "{" and "}".